# Pronunciation of "thank" using ð (voiced th) instead of θ (unvoiced th)

Tags: pronunciation

Both my younger siblings pronounce "thank" using ð, voicing the "th". I have never heard any other native speaker pronounce it this way. Both my parents, my older sibling, and I all pronounce "thank" using θ, not voicing the "th". I am really wondering where they got this pronunciation form from. From what I have found, the standard pronunciation of "thank" is always with θ.

Has anyone else ever heard "thank" pronounced using ð? Are there any English dialects in which this might be correct?

Comment: Not any I know of, but one thing's for certain, your younger siblings are pronouncing the word incorrectly. Maybe you could teach them the correct way? As for their mistake, I would imagine them to be really young, because the problem seems to lie in setting a rule of thumb for pronouncing "th" in one particular way i.e with  ð for every single word.

Comment: They learned *than* (as in *better than*) before they **saw** the word *thank* in print -- they need to be corrected.

Comment: @Kris Probably an excellent deduction.

Comment: In parts of New England, US, "thank you" is often pronounced with the "th" sound in "the".

Comment: @Oldbag That doesn't make it right -- Bostonians also mispronounce _car_ as _cah_.

Comment: Well "right" is relative. There is no universally recognized authority for pronunciation, and widespread regional variation.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially [the same question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/15447/voiced-th-in-thank-you) was also posted on the linguistics stackexchange, several months after the posting of the present question here on the English stackexchange. As of Jan 14, 2016, here is what we have learned there:

1. At the present time, there does seem to exist a subgroup of adult native English speakers who pronounce the "th" as voiced. It is not clear if there is any underlying reason for this that would be common to all or even most of them. There do seem to exist some regional tendencies (see 2. below), but it seems there must be some other factors at play as well (see 3. below).
2. There indeed exists some published research on this: the Survey of English Dialects (Orton et al. 1962-71) recorded "a number of instances of the voicing of all four fricatives in word-initial (Anlaut) position in the South and the South-West Midlands" (Fisiak 1988); see [Voitl 1988](http://www.degruyter.com/view/books/9783110848137/9783110848137.565/9783110848137.565.xml?format=EBOK) (also [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=ptAb7J1DUZAC&lpg=PA565&ots=A9kr9JyWxi&dq=%22The%20history%20of%20voicing%20of%20initial%20fricatives%20in%20Southern%20England%22&pg=PA565#v=onepage&q=%22The%20history%20of%20voicing%20of%20initial%20fricatives%20in%20Southern%20England%22&f=false)). Related research includes that by Martyn Wakelin, esp. Wakelin and Barry (1968) (thanks to Alex B. for all of this).
3. From the comments by musicallinguist, it seems that sometimes even among siblings raised in the same household (of native English speakers, in an English-speaking country) there can be a difference in the voicing of the initial "th," which then *persists into adulthood*. References to published research on this aspect would be most welcome.